# Cmake-gui not coming up on windows

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I am using Cmake-gui and it was working fine, suddenly it started crashing. Whenever i try to open it, it gets added to the taskbar but app doesn't open. I waited for many hours also. I tried installing previous versions also but same thing is happening. I am using windows 10 amd Cmake version 3.16.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved my issue by removing the following key from the windows registry :
`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Kitware\CMakeSetup`

It contained all the settings of my last run of Cmake. Some of them became invalid due to changes on my system.

Deleting the key has reset the settings to default and cMake-gui launched successfully.

Comment: I needed to delete all of `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Kitware` which contained two sub keys, i.e. `CMake`, and `CMakeSetup`.